# Проблемы с установкой PostgreSQL на Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Пытаюсь установить PostgreSQL. На запрос

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

> Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости: postgresql : Зависит:
>   postgresql-10 но он не будет установлен E: Невозможно исправить
>   ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```

> Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости: postgresql-10 :
>   Зависит: postgresql-client-10 но он не будет установлен Зависит:
>   postgresql-common (>= 182~) но он не будет установлен Зависит:
>   libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) но он не может быть установлен Зависит:
>   libsystemd0 но он не может быть установлен Рекомендует: sysstat но он
>   не будет установлен E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены
>   (held) битые пакеты.

Пытался установить каждую зависимость, но все приводит к ошибкам. Использую Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Проблема не в PostgreSQL, а в проблемах с менеджером пакетов.

Comment: Я чайник в исправлении проблем в менеджере пакетов, может вы объясните на пальцах как быть дальше?

Comment: Гуглить по запросу "apt held", экспериментировать с найденным, разбираться.

Comment: Вопрос решен! надо было покопаться в директории /etc/apt/sources.list.d и удалить там строку в файле pgpg одну строку, с репозиторием для xenial

Comment: И по-хорошему ещё выполнить

"sudo apt-get -f install" 

без имени пакета - эта команда проверит и починит недоустановленные зависимости

Comment: проделывал эту комманду,когда была проблема - не помогла. Так же сделал после. все пакеты по нулям!